# What is the maximum account name length in NEAR blockchain?

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm using account name as a key in various places, and would like to know them maximum account name length to compute storage cost bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum length is 64 bytes.
More details: https://nomicon.io/DataStructures/Account

Answer (score -1):

The maximum account name length in the NEAR blockchain is 32 characters